# how to hide HTML tags when sending email by SMTP and tinymce for writting content

Tags: php, html, email, smtp

I just want to send emails to costumers who has bought something...
I use SMTP and PHP to send it but in SMTP codes I defined the content of email content to be received from a text area which uses tinymce..All Is fine and it sends the email but in emails sent,  there are HTML tags used to write the content in tinymce editor...the tags should be treated as HTML tags not as a string...I set every thing relevant to HTML in SMTP codes(as showed i the bottom)but that's not going to work...

`

```
<form action="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']) ?>" method="post">
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="subject">subject</label>
        <input type="text" id="subject" name="subject" class="form-control" />
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="msg">content</label>
        <textarea id="msg" name="msg" class="form-control"></textarea>
    </div>
    <input type="submit" value="send" class="btn btn-success" name="submit"/>
   </form>    
$q = 'SELECT * FROM Users';
    $re = $conn->query($q);
    $row = $re->fetch_assoc();
    while($row = $re->fetch_assoc()){
    require_once 'phpMailer5/class.phpmailer.php';
    require_once 'phpMailer5/class.smtp.php';
    $mail = new PHPMailer();
    $mail->isSMTP();
    $mail->Host = 'localhost';
    $mail->Username = 'etc@example.etc';
    $mail->Password = 'something';
    $mail->Subject  = xss_clean($_POST['subject']);
    //$mail->SMTPDebug = 2;
    $mail->Debugoutput = 'html';
    $mail->SMTPAuth = true;
    $mail->CharSet = 'UTF-8';
    $mail->AddBCC($row['email'],$row['name']);
    $mail->isHTML(true);
    //$mail->MsgHTML(stripslashes(stripslashes(xss_clean($_POST['msg']))));
    $mail->Body = stripslashes(stripslashes(xss_clean($_POST['msg'])));
    $mail->AltBody = xss_clean($_POST['msg']);
    $mail->setFrom('no-reply@example.etc','Mahyar Ansary');
    if(!$mail->Send()){
        echo '<div class="alert alert-danger">'.$mail->ErrorInfo.'</div>';
    }
    else{
        echo '<div class="alert alert-success">sent</div>';
    }
```

`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just used `htmlspecialchars_decode()`.

Answer (score 0):

Set the `content-type` to `text/html` in the headers. I.e `$mail->IsHTML(true);`

Comment: sorry but if you see my codes I just set it `$mail->isHTML(true)` !that's not gonna work